# Formatting xml for buttons at bottm

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am trying to make a layout where the last button will always be at the bottom and will be able to scroll if needed. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/NameDesc"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Spot Name:"
    style="@style/black_text"/>

<!-- Input Name -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:capitalize="words"/>



        <!-- Button Create Product -->
<Button android:id="@+id/btnDate" 
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set Date"
    android:tag="3"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:visibility="gone"
   style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>
        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date of Event:"
    style="@style/black_text"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

   <Button android:id="@+id/btnTime" 
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set Time"
    android:tag="4"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:visibility="gone"
    style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>

                <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTime"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time of Event:"
    style="@style/black_text"
    android:visibility="gone"/>



    <!--Type in info^ -->

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtType"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Event Type:"
    style="@style/black_text"
     android:visibility="gone"
/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_event"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/event_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/event_prompt" 
     android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pavement Type:"
    style="@style/black_text"
/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_pavement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/pavement_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/pavement_prompt" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Amount of Traffic:"
    style="@style/black_text"
/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_traffic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:entries="@array/traffic_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/traffic_prompt" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Environment Type:"
    style="@style/black_text"
/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_enviro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:entries="@array/enviro_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/enviro_prompt" />

            <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCapturePicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take a Picture"
        android:tag="1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPreview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Image Preview:" 
        style="@style/black_text"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <!-- To display picture taken -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>
     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <!-- Button Create Product -->
<Button android:id="@+id/btnCreate" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create Spot"
    android:tag="2"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But I cannot get the last button to go at the bottom. Could  someone please help me? I have tried a couple answers on here but none seemed to work. Maybe it was because of how I set the height of the other layouts but I'm not too sure on that.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this my implementations in some projects  i think it will help you to determine your layout , 
 may help you  and feel free to feed me back in any issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FC9"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Fixed Header"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FC0"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Fixed Footer"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:background="#005" >
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! That layout really helped alot! I'm probably going to go through all my xml layouts and replace them with that. It really organizes it better than what I had!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way I can think of is to use `RelativeLayout`. It has the member `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` which you can use in your Button within the RelativeLayout. This will always keep it at bottommost.

Comment: Can I just nest the relativelayout into the linearlayout and just include the button in the relative? or does the whole thing need to be relative?

Comment: The outermost need to be Relative Layout.